# How to use check_mysql_health plugin on windows?

Tags: mysql, nagios

How to use check_mysql_health plugin on windows, please list down all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

This link - http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_mysql_health/ 
explains the installation of check_mysql_health

- Assuming you have Nagios setup ready
- Assuming you have followed all the steps mentioned my the excellent gentleman who created the plugin
- assuming you have allowed MySQL through windows firewall
- assuming you have user who can access all the USAGE information of MySQL (you can use root user)
- assuming you can access the windows MySQL server from the Nagios machine (using the same user in step above)

The task is accomplished. *(Or I have not understood question at all)*

*Do you still need steps ?*